# What is a good way to get keyboard Input in Python/Pygame?

Tags: python, input, pygame

I am making a pygame program where I have a string and whatever the user types it displays it in the pygame window. Here is the code:

```
    if (event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN):
                    if (event.key==pygame.K_BACKSPACE):
                            if (len(sin)>0):
                                    sin=""
                    elif (event.key==pygame.K_RETURN):
                            if (len(sin)==11):
                                    #sin.replace("-","")
                                    running=2
                                    screen.fill(white)
                            else:
                                    body=True

                    else:
                            sin=sin+chr(event.key)
    text=font.render(sin,True,(black),white)
```

One problem is that it does not recognize special characters like (":",";",shift characters etc.) Is there a better way to code something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `event.unicode` to [get what you are looking for](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html).

> ... The pygame.KEYDOWN event has an additional attributes unicode, and
>   scancode. unicode represents a single character string that is the
>   fully translated character entered. ...

---

To answer your comment you just check `event.unicode` instead of `event.key`:

```
...
if (event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN):
    if (event.unicode==pygame.K_COLON): #to match a colon
        pass
    elif (event.unicode== (pygame.K_Z | pygame.KMOD_SHIFT)): #to explicitly match a capital Z instead of just a z
       pass
...
```

Comment: This is what I have so far:
for event in pygame.event.get():
   if (event.type == KEYDOWN):
    str1=str1+event.unicode
    print str1
but for some reason the input "lags"

Comment: Thanks I got it to display it on the pygame window, one more question: if I did "Backspace", how would i delete the last letter in a string? Would I need to convert it into a list and pop it?

Comment: you can slice strings just like any list: aka `a = "Hello"` then `a = a[:-1]` to remove the last character

Comment: also do not forget to mark my answer as correct if it helps you out :) the little 'empty' checkmark that turns green when clicked or hovered :)

Comment: I think that `event.unicode` and `pygame.K_Z` (capitalization) and `KMOD_SHIFT` (you’d need `event.key` and `KMOD_LSHIFT`/`KMOD_RSHIFT`, right?) in the `elif` are wrong. I would suggest an edit, but I don’t have time to test it or know the right way off the top of my head xD.